# Trigger after insert not working correctly after multiple inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have a trigger that is fired after insert. It triggers a stored procedure that updates column `IsLast` in table `CompanyStatus`

```
Id | CompanyId | Status | DateCreated | IsLast
```

This stored procedure should set `1` in `IsLast` column for record with largest `Id`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCompanyStatusAfterInsert](@schemaName nvarchar(100),  @dataTable CompanyStatus READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @sql = N'DECLARE
        @Id bigint,
        @companyId uniqueidentifier;

        DECLARE CompanyStatus_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT Id, CompanyId
        FROM @dataTable

        OPEN CompanyStatus_Cursor 

        FETCH NEXT FROM CompanyStatus_Cursor 
        INTO @Id, @companyId

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName ) + N'.[CompanyStatus]
            SET IsLast = 0
            WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id
                         FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.[CompanyStatus]
                         WHERE Id <> @Id
                               AND CompanyId = @companyId
                               AND IsLast = 1) 

            UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.[CompanyStatus]
            SET IsLast = 1
            WHERE Id = @Id

            FETCH NEXT FROM crs
            INTO @Id, @companyId
        END

        CLOSE CompanyStatus_Cursor 
        DEALLOCATE CompanyStatus_Cursor'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@schemaName nvarchar(100), @dataTable CompanyStatus READONLY', @schemaName, @dataTable
END
```

(Firstly updates all existing `IsLast` to `0` and then set `1` to latest `Id` - this is expected behavior).

Problem - when I do 2 inserts in a very short time, in result I get 2 records with `IsLast = 1`.

```
Id | CompanyId                            | Status | DateCreated             | IsLast
19 | 8afbd9cb-02f9-45d7-a605-a54052866bd4 | 1      | 2019-04-01 12:08:59.540 | 1
18 | 8afbd9cb-02f9-45d7-a605-a54052866bd4 | 1      | 2019-04-01 12:10:57.790 | 1
17 | fc7d1f2b-a72a-4d7f-99fa-602c72fb0410 | 2      | 2019-03-30 12:14:57.294 | 1
16 | 8afbd9cb-02f9-45d7-a605-a54052866bd4 | 1      | 2019-03-29 12:10:57.790 | 0
```

In example row with Id `18` shoudn't be with `IsLast = 1` as there are row with larger Id.

---

Is problem in the time of execution of this update-queries? (the first update isn't finished before second is started).

---

Trigger code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [{schema}].[{schema}_TRG_CompanyStatus]
ON [{schema}].[CompanyStatus]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @dataTable CompanyStatus

    INSERT INTO @dataTable SELECT Id, CompanyId  FROM inserted

    EXEC [dbo].[spCompanyStatusAfterInsert] N'{schema}', @dataTable
END

GO
```

Comment: Why is your SP using `sp_executesql` when it has no dynamic statements in it? And why a `CURSOR`, that looks like it could easily be achieved with a set based operation in the trigger itself.

Comment: So is that not actually what your actual SP is? If so, to debug it, we really need to see your real code. If that is your actual SP, then your comment doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: Your logic is really quite flawed here. You have a cursor where you seem to expect order. But you have no order by. Then you update the whole table each iteration through the cursor and effectively undo the changes you made in the last iteration. Why??? This screams of poor design and being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I would suggest that a single update to the one you want would make more sense than a cursor here.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better for you to show us the data your inserted, and then the results you're after and why.

Comment: @SeanLange, after some time, I think I've found a reason for cursor - in case it is batch insert (row can be related to different `CompanyId`s). Even though, from code I do single inserts (using different commands) in very short time, this cause my issue. I've tried to check if in `inserted` table there are the largest ids for company (if no - IsLast = 0 will not be changed), but this doesn't resolve problem

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What purpose does the isLast column serve? Does it identify the "last" row inserted (or updated - not clear) or does it identify the row with the highest value in ID column? Finding the highest ID value typically requires trivial effort by the database engine. So why do you need to do this?

Comment: Ummm....not sure how batch inserts and a cursor inside a trigger make sense. That trigger and the subsequent cursor are a mess. It needs a complete rewrite as it is just an exercise in how to slow things down right now.

Answer (score 0):

test this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCompanyStatusAfterInsert](@schemaName nvarchar(100),  @dataTable CompanyStatus READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @sql = N'

            UPDATE tab
            SET IsLast = CASE src.id WHEN tab.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName ) + N'.[CompanyStatus] tab
            INNER JOIN @dataTable src
            ON tab.CompanyId = src.companyId
            WHERE tab.id = src.id or tab.IsLast=1
    '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@schemaName nvarchar(100), @dataTable CompanyStatus READONLY', @schemaName, @dataTable
END
```